# What is the ext. or mime-type of open-ssh-certs? (Puttygen)

Tags: ssl-certificate, mime-types, putty, openssh

i usualy use puttygen(windoz) to generate ppk-files and open-ssh-certificates (i write an ajax-web-putty using "Java Server Faces").

In putty-gen-menu i select "Conversions->Export OpenSSH Key" but no default-extesion is given!

```
Is even there an specific ext/mime-type?
```

Regards